# error TS2742: The inferred type of X cannot be named without a reference to

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

I am building simple SDK for Polkadot Api calls. I am running into following issue trying to build it:

```
error TS2742: The inferred type of 'closeChannel' cannot be named without a reference to '.pnpm/@polkadot+types@8.14.1/node_modules/@polkadot/types/types'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
```

Code that I get error on is API function to close HRMP channels for specific node:

```
import type { ApiPromise } from '@polkadot/api'

export function closeChannel(api: ApiPromise, origin: number, inbound: number, outbound: number) {
    return api.tx.hrmp.forceCleanHrmp(origin,inbound,outbound)
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I see no errors before compilation. Thanks in advance!